# combining two slicing operations

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a smart and easy way to combine two slicing operations into one?

Say I have something like

```
arange(1000)[::2][10:20]
>>> array([20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38])
```

Of course in this example this is not a problem, but if the arrays are very large I would very much like to avoid creating the intermediate array (or is there none?). I believe it should be possible to combine the two slices but maybe I'm overseeing something.
So the idea would be something like:

```
arange(1000)[ slice(None,None,2) + slice(10,20,None) ]
```

This of course does not work but is what i would like to do. Is there anything that does combine slicing objects? (despite my efforts I did not find anything).

Comment: You have to keep in mind that when slicing numpy arrays, you aren't copying any data, just changing your view on the data in memory.  Slicing is `O(1)` complexity, so creating intermediate arrays isn't a big deal.

Comment: That is an excellent point, so I guess that is why there is nothing build in like that. However I would like to save the slices that should be made to a matrix to get the data I want in an Object. Of course one could just save all the slices in a list, however it feels like there should be a way to combine them in a smart way and save it then

Comment: If you want to go that route, I would suggest storing your slices as boolean arrays, then you can combine them with logical operators and use the resultant as your "slice".  Unfortunately, this wouldn't be very flexible if you want to handle arrays of multiple sizes.  If you made a function to do this, you could pass in your slices as `*args` and have that function handle all the computations necessary to create the right boolean array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can subclass `slice` to make such superposition of slices possible. Just override `__add__` (or `__mul__` - a mathematician would surely prefer `*` notation for superposition). But it is going to invoke some math. By the way, you could make a nice Python package with this stuff ;-)
2. As [**bheklilr** said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257498/combining-two-slicing-operations#comment28817260_19257498), slicing costs nothing in NumPy. So you can just go on with a simple solution like list of slices.

**P. S.** In general, multiple slicing can be used to make code nicer and much more clear. Even a simple choice between one of the following lines:

```
v = A[::2][10:20]
v = A[20:40][::2]
v = A[20:40:2]
```

can deeply reflect program logic, making code self-documenting.

One more example: if you have a flat NumPy array and you wish to extract a subarray in position `position` of length `length`, you can do

```
v = A[position : position + length]
```

or

```
v = A[position:][:length]
```

Decide for yourself which option looks better. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As @Tigran said, slicing costs nothing when using Numpy arrays. However, in general we can combine two slices in series using info from [slice.indices](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/slice.html), which

> Retrieve[s] the start, stop, and step indices from the slice object slice assuming a sequence of length length

We can reduce

```
x[slice1][slice2]
```

to

```
x[combined]
```

The first slicing returns a new object, which is then sliced by the second slicing. So, we'll also need the length of our data object to combine the slices properly. (Length in the *first* dimension)

So, we can write

```
def slice_combine(slice1, slice2, length):
    """
    returns a slice that is a combination of the two slices.
    As in 
      x[slice1][slice2]
    becomes
      combined_slice = slice_combine(slice1, slice2, len(x))
      x[combined_slice]

    :param slice1: The first slice
    :param slice2: The second slice
    :param length: The length of the first dimension of data being sliced. (eg len(x))
    """

    # First get the step sizes of the two slices.
    slice1_step = (slice1.step if slice1.step is not None else 1)
    slice2_step = (slice2.step if slice2.step is not None else 1)

    # The final step size
    step = slice1_step * slice2_step

    # Use slice1.indices to get the actual indices returned from slicing with slice1
    slice1_indices = slice1.indices(length)

    # We calculate the length of the first slice
    slice1_length = (abs(slice1_indices[1] - slice1_indices[0]) - 1) // abs(slice1_indices[2])

    # If we step in the same direction as the start,stop, we get at least one datapoint
    if (slice1_indices[1] - slice1_indices[0]) * slice1_step > 0:
        slice1_length += 1
    else:
        # Otherwise, The slice is zero length.
        return slice(0,0,step)

    # Use the length after the first slice to get the indices returned from a
    # second slice starting at 0.
    slice2_indices = slice2.indices(slice1_length)

    # if the final range length = 0, return
    if not (slice2_indices[1] - slice2_indices[0]) * slice2_step > 0:
        return slice(0,0,step)

    # We shift slice2_indices by the starting index in slice1 and the 
    # step size of slice1
    start = slice1_indices[0] + slice2_indices[0] * slice1_step
    stop = slice1_indices[0] + slice2_indices[1] * slice1_step

    # slice.indices will return -1 as the stop index when slice.stop should be set to None.
    if start > stop:
        if stop < 0:
            stop = None

    return slice(start, stop, step)
```

Then, let's run some tests

```
import sys
import numpy as np

# Make a 1D dataset
x = np.arange(100)
l = len(x)

# Make a (100, 10) dataset
x2 = np.arange(1000)
x2 = x2.reshape((100,10))
l2 = len(x2)

# Test indices and steps
indices = [None, -1000, -100, -99, -50, -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, 50, 99, 100, 1000]
steps = [-1000, -99, -50, -10, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 10, 50, 99, 1000]
indices_l = len(indices)
steps_l = len(steps)

count = 0
total = 2 * indices_l**4 * steps_l**2
for i in range(indices_l):
    for j in range(indices_l):
        for k in range(steps_l):
            for q in range(indices_l):
                for r in range(indices_l):
                    for s in range(steps_l):
                        # Print the progress. There are a lot of combinations.
                        if count % 5197 == 0:
                            sys.stdout.write("\rPROGRESS: {0:,}/{1:,} ({2:.0f}%)".format(count, total, float(count) / float(total) * 100))
                            sys.stdout.flush()

                        slice1 = slice(indices[i], indices[j], steps[k])
                        slice2 = slice(indices[q], indices[r], steps[s])

                        combined = slice_combine(slice1, slice2, l)
                        combined2 = slice_combine(slice1, slice2, l2)
                        np.testing.assert_array_equal(x[slice1][slice2], x[combined], 
                            err_msg="For 1D, slice1: {0},\tslice2: {1},\tcombined: {2}\tCOUNT: {3}".format(slice1, slice2, combined, count))
                        np.testing.assert_array_equal(x2[slice1][slice2], x2[combined2], 
                            err_msg="For 2D, slice1: {0},\tslice2: {1},\tcombined: {2}\tCOUNT: {3}".format(slice1, slice2, combined2, count))

                        # 2 tests per loop
                        count += 2

print("\n-----------------")
print("All {0:,} tests passed!".format(count))
```

And thankfully we get

> All 15,059,072 tests passed!

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, the built-in [range](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#range) object can do the calculation for you without expanding to fill memory:

```python
def combine_slices(length, *slices):
    r = range(length)   # length of array being sliced
    for s in slices:
        r = r[s]
    return slice(r.start, r.stop, r.step)

arr = range(-2**48, 2**48)   # simulate a huge array
s = combine_slices(len(arr), slice(2**48,None), slice(None,None,2), slice(10,20,None))

print(arr[s] == arr[2**48:][::2][10:20])    # => True
print(list(arr[s]))     # => [20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38]
print(s)    # => slice(281474976710676, 281474976710696, 2)
```

Comment: I don't think this works. Try slicing 1:3 and 9:12 and combining them using this.

Comment: @mathtick In that order, they're disjoint, so the result is an empty list, as expected.  In the other order, I also get correct results.  I'm not sure what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Here an imporved version of @dlitz code that passes @well tests.

```py
def combine_slices(length, *slices):
    r = range(length)
    for s in slices:
        r = r[s]
    if len(r) == 0:
        return slice(0)
    elif r.stop < 0:
        return slice(r.start, None, r.step)
    else:
        return slice(r.start, r.stop, r.step)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `islice`, which probably won't be any faster, but will avoid the intermediate entries by working as a generator:

```
arange = range(1000)

from itertools import islice
islice(islice(arange, None, None, 2), 10, 20)

%timeit list(islice(islice(arange, None, None, 2), 10, 20))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2 us per loop

%timeit arange[::2][10:20]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.64 us per loop
```

So, a little faster.

Comment: Again, only makes sense for non-numpy.

Answer (score -1):

very simple:

```
arange(1000)[20:40:2]
```

should do

Comment: I think the OP is looking for something more generic not requiring updating values by hand.

Comment: Well, thank you very much for pointing that out, but indeed I was looking for a general solution. I can see how that was my fault for not stating that outright.